# Toggle button works in one direction only

Tags: javascript, jquery

My toggle button logic (the last code block in under the `<script>` tag) only seems to work in one direction. Specifically, the temperature, `temp`, variable arrives at this section of code in Celsius. On button click, everything successfully converts to Fahrenheit, but then the button stops working. Note, I tried an alternate design using closures, embedding everything in the updateTemp function, changing the button's id with every click, and axing the top two variables under `$(document).ready`. It was a mess and still didn't provide the toggle functionality I was looking for. Thoughts?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- CSS -->

        <!-- JS/JQ -->
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var tempType = 0;
            var temp = 0;
            var coords = {
              lat: 0,
              lon: 0
            };
            // retrieve and set user's latitude and longitude coordinates
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                    coords.lon = position.coords.longitude;
                    coords.lat = position.coords.latitude;
                    // AJAX called here b/c getCurrentPosition is asynchronous
                    sendAJAX(coords);
                });
            } else {
                alert("Sorry, I couldn't locate you. Here's the weather elsewhere.");
                coords.lon = 48.8566;
                coords.lat = 2.3522;
                sendAJAX(coords);
            }
            // AJAX request and settings wrapped in fxn for ease of calling within if/else
            function sendAJAX (coords) {
                // enumerate AJAX request settings & pass in coordinate settings
                var ajaxOptions = {
                    crossDomain:true,
                    dataType:"json",
                    url:"https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?",
                    data: {
                        lon:coords.lon,
                        lat:coords.lat
                    },
                    method:"GET"
                };
                // attached .done() fxn calls used here, as they rely on the JSON file returned by the AJAX request
                $.ajax(ajaxOptions).done(updateCity).done(updateIcon).done(updateDesc).done(updateTemp).done(updateHumid).done(updateWind);
            }
            // update weather icon on page
            function updateCity (json) {
                var cityHTML = "";
                cityHTML += json.name + ", " +  json.sys.country;
                $("#city").html(cityHTML);
            }
            // update weather icon on page
            function updateIcon (json) {
                var iconHTML = "";
                iconHTML += "<img src='" + json.weather[0].icon + "'";
                iconHTML += "alt='weather icon'>";
                $("#icon").html(iconHTML);
            }
            // update description of weather on page
            function updateDesc (json) {
                var descHTML = "";
                var desc = json.weather[0].main;
                descHTML += desc;
                $("#descript").html(descHTML);
                changeImage(desc);
            }
            // update temperature
            function updateTemp (json) {
                var tempHTML = "";
                // the 0x in front of the character code matters, no truncation allowed despite what some docs might seem to suggest
                temp = Math.round(json.main.temp);
                var degree = String.fromCharCode(0x2103);
                tempHTML += temp + degree;
                $("#temp").html(tempHTML);

            }
            // update humidity
            function updateHumid (json) {
                var humidHTML = "";
                var percent = String.fromCharCode(0x0025);
                humidHTML += json.main.humidity + percent;
                $("#humidity").html(humidHTML);
            }
            // update wind speed
            function updateWind (json) {
                var windHTML = "";
                windHTML += json.wind.speed + " knots";
                $("#wind").html(windHTML);
            }
            // change background image
            function changeImage (desc) {
                if (desc.match(/Clear/)) {
                    $("body").css("background-image", "url(img/clear.jpg)");
                } else if (desc.match(/Rain/)) {
                    $("body").css("background-image", "url(img/rain.jpg)");
                } else if (desc.match(/Haze/)) {
                    $("body").css("background-image", "url(img/haze.jpg)");
                } else if (desc.match(/Clouds/)) {
                    $("body").css("background-image", "url(img/cloudy.jpg)");
                } else if (desc.match(/Snow/)) {
                    $("body").css("background-image", "url(img/snow.jpg)");
                } else {
                    $("body").css("background-image", "url(img/default.jpg)");
                }
            }
            // toggle button logic
            if (tempType == "0") {
                $("#convert").on("click", function () {
                    var fahrenheit = Math.round((9/5)*(temp) + 32);
                    var tempFarHTML = "";
                    var degree = String.fromCharCode(0x2109);
                    tempFarHTML += fahrenheit + degree;
                    $("#temp").html(tempFarHTML);
                    $("#convert").html("Convert to Celsius");
                    tempType == "1";
                });
            } else {
                $("#convert").on("click", function () {
                    var celsius = temp;
                    var tempCelsiusHTML = "";
                    var degree = String.fromCharCode(0x2103);
                    tempCelsiusHTML += celsius + degree;
                    $("#temp").html(tempCelsiusHTML);
                    $("#convert").html("Convert to Celsius");
                    tempType == "0";
                });
            }

        });
        </script>
        <title>Local Weather</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div id="page-title" class="col-md-12">
                    The Local Weather
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div id="city" class="col-md-12">
                    City
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center">
                <h2>Current Conditions</h2>
                <div id="icon" class="col-md-12 img-responsive">
                    Icon
                </div>
                <div id="descript" class="col-md-12">
                    Desc
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h2>Temperature</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h2>Humidity</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h2>Wind</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div id="temp" class="col-md-4">
                    Temp
                </div>
                <div id="humidity" class="col-md-4">
                    Humid
                </div>
                <div id="wind" class="col-md-4">
                    Wind
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div id="temp" class="col-md-4">
                    <button id="convert" class="btn btn-default">Convert to Fahrenheit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a duplicate id  ("temp")  so that will be messing with your code function.

Comment: Thoughts - are there any console errors? When you place a breakpoint and step through debug, what happens differently between the toggle positions?

Comment: Just a few tips that I've learned pretty recently that helped me clean up my code too. Instead of using the html id to identify elements, use data- attributes `data-el="temp"` this lets you completely separate html/css from js. Also, in your js define html elements at the top, e.g. `var tempElement = '[data-el="temp"]'` This makes it easy to make updates in the future, and you're not repeating code. Finally, instead of var, consider using let; this is ES6 syntax which is ready in all updated browsers, but not old browsers, so you will want to transpile if you need to support older browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition should be checked inside of the function as follows:

```
            // toggle button logic

                $("#convert").on("click", function () {
                    if (tempType == "0") {
                        var fahrenheit = Math.round((9/5)*(temp) + 32);
                        var tempFarHTML = "";
                        var degree = String.fromCharCode(0x2109);
                        tempFarHTML += fahrenheit + degree;
                        $("#temp").html(tempFarHTML);
                        $("#convert").html("Convert to Celsius");
                        tempType == "1";
                        temp = fahrenheit;
                    } else {
                        var celsius = temp;
                        var tempCelsiusHTML = "";
                        var degree = String.fromCharCode(0x2103);
                        tempCelsiusHTML += celsius + degree;
                        $("#temp").html(tempCelsiusHTML);
                        $("#convert").html("Convert to Celsius");
                        tempType == "0";
                        temp = celsius
                    });
                });
```

Also, as mentioned by @gavgrif in a comment on the question, there is a duplicate id "temp", which should be corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
tempType == "1";
```

I think you're looking for one equal sign

```
tempType = "1";
```

Comment: Yup. When I was looking at the answer above I noticed this. Now tempType updates, but still no conversion from Fahrenheit back to Celsius.

Answer (score 1):

When your page is loaded, your *tempType* is 0 and on click event is registered on your convert div to change the value to farenheit.

When the onClick event is triggered and your conversion works for the first time, however your onClick event doesn't change as your page isn't loaded again and your onClick event stays the same even though your *tempType* is set to 1. You need to change the way you try to solve your problem, you must reload the whole page or make a function that changes your onClick event, and assign it to your button, however that is not a good practice and would be considered to be an anti-pattern. The best approach would be to move the if-else condition inside the onClick event.

Comment: I was with you until "make a function that changes your onClick event" - I would consider that to be an antipattern.  Your final suggestion of moving the condition inside the onClick event should be preferred.

Comment: @thisguyheisaguy I agree with you. I just wanted to list all the possibilities. I will edit my answer to point that out.